# CAML Query to get next month events in a sharepoint calendar list

Tags: sharepoint-2007, calendar, caml

The following CAML query can retrieve events related to current month,

```
<Query><Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name="EventDate" /><FieldRef Name="EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Month /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where></Query>
```

How do i get events of upcoming month from sharepoint calendar list using CAML query?